# ASP.Net MVC File upload - Maximum uploaded - Safari exceed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've set a max file size, but it appears that safari users can get around the max size?

```
...
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120"/>
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5000000" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
...
```

When I try to upload a 16mb via google chrome it seems to work (ie not upload)
Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: web.config xml you posted is bad, you have 2 opening `system.webServer` elements

Comment: sorry my bad typo,